# XML Error debug

Tags: xml, debugging, debug

I need to debug the following error but I don't know how. They seems XML related. Is there a way to know where to search?

```
> 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
> Entity: line 126: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:
> action line 121 and reference  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():         &lt;/reference&gt;  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():                     ^  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 127: parser error : Opening and
> ending tag mismatch: reference line 120 and customer_account  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():     &lt;/customer_account&gt;  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():                        ^  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 137: parser error : Opening and
> ending tag mismatch: customer_account line 119 and layout  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string(): &lt;/layout&gt;  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():          ^  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 138: parser error : Premature
> end of data in tag layout line 28  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string():   in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450 2015-11-19T21:58:55+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
> simplexml_load_string(): ^  in
> /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php
> on line 450
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check again .xml file in `etc` and `layout` folder because it opening and ending tag mismatch.